# CSS acessibility :focus customization problems

Tags: css, css-selectors, focus, css-transitions, accessibility

I'm trying to customize the :focus for my website so I can keep accessibility top priority but make it themely. I've tabindexed all things that should be and I've added code that I thought should do what I want but it still just gives me the natural blue glowing outline instead of my eased pink glowing one. What am I doing wrong here?

```
a:focus, a:hover {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(255, 0, 255, 1);
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
  margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 255, 1);
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

**Edit:** This is the link element in the html (added as mentioned in comment)

```
<div tabindex="1" class="buttonpressed">Home</div>
<a href="intro.html">
  <div tabindex="2" class="button buttonlinks">Introduction</div>
</a>
```

Comment: Works for me https://jsfiddle.net/qt1cxLy9/

Comment: I wonder why it's not working on mine?

Comment: I inspected one of my button elements and the a:focus is not even showing as acting on the button link. Why could that be?

Comment: 1: Check your stylesheet path, 2: Specificity(to check this move your CSS in HTML document between style tags and see if it works, if it does, it's specificity issue)... there are the only two points which can be responsible for your styles not being applied.

Comment: This is what I did:

`     <style>`
`    a:focus, a:hover {`
`    outline: none;`
`    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(255, 0, 255, 1);`
`    padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;`
`    margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;`
`    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 255, 1);`
`    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;`
`    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;`
`    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;`
`    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;`
`    }`
`    </style>`
`    <div tabindex="1" class="buttonpressed">Home</div>`
`    <a href="intro.html"><div tabindex="2" class="button buttonlinks">Introduction</div></a>`

It didn't work.

Comment: Please do not add these kind of infos as a comment - just click on the "edit" link below your question to improve it and add the relevant codes and additional informations directly within your question post. Thank you. To your question: shouldn't tabindex be in the link element? `<a href="..." tabindex="...">`

Comment: Sorry about that. I didn't think you were supposed to change previous answers. I have the tabindex where it is because I want the whole div to hilite, not just the linked text. Can you suggest why my pink glow effect isn't applying?

Comment: A clarification question might help resolve why there seems to be an inconsistency between results of others and you work. Have you tabbed all the way to the anchor?

Are you aware that adding positive tabindex attributes puts those elements before your anchor in tab order? With the current setup users are focusing on the div inside of the anchor before they can focus on the anchor.

Comment: If I move the tabindex to the a link, nothing changes. What is a better suggestion? I want the whole div to be the clickable link, not just the text inside. That's why I did it that way.

Comment: Do not add `tabindex` with values greater than 0. This can severely hamper a user's experience. In fact, avoid being in a situation where you need a `tabindex`. Post a real example, we may be able to help you use the right element and achieve the effect you want.

Comment: That IS a real example, and it seems I misunderstood how tabindex works. Let me try fixing it and see if that works. Thanks for pointing that out.